# Bash history - remember escaped new lines

Tags: bash, readline

I have long chains of piped commands that I would like formatted over multiple lines (and recall for further editing using "fc")

How do I get bash history to remember to escaped new lines added for formatting?

For instance, if I type:

```
$ echo a b c \
>  | grep a
a b c
```

History recalls it with the escaped new line removed:

```
$ echo a b c  | grep a
```

I know that I can use `shopt -s lithist` to make non-escaped new lines to show up: 
For example, after running:

```
$ shopt -s lithist
```

The below command:

```
$ for X in a b c; do
> echo $X
> done
a
b
c
```

is recalled as:

```
$ for X in a b c; do
echo $X
done
```

But this does not retain formatting for escaped newlines (which are required to format pipe chains).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think what you want is exactly possible. The bash man page states:

```
If a \<newline> pair appears, and the backslash is not
itself quoted, the \<newline> is treated as a line continuation (that
is, it is removed from the input stream and effectively ignored).
```

One way you can get around this is, with the `lithist` shell option, simply reformat your code. So instead of this:

```
$ echo a b c \
>  | grep a
a b c
```

Do this:

```
$ echo a b c |
> grep a
```

You don't actually *need* to put the \ at the end of the line - if you can show bash that input is expected, it waits for the next line anyway. (You may already know this, but) this also works for multiple lines of input:

```
$ echo 'one
> two
> three'
one
two
three
```

**Edit:** in response to the question asked via a comment below, about how to possibly pass multiple command line options on separate lines.

The only way I can think of is by defining the options beforehand in an array, and then passing that as a command line parameter. eg:

```
$ opts=(
> -s 'test'
> someone@example.com
> )
$ mutt ${opts[*]}  # launches: mutt -s someone@example.com
```

Comment: Thanks! That addresses most of my use cases. Is there any trick for having commandline switches, one per line like:
mycommand \
   --name1 --value1 \
   --name2 --value2 \
   ...

Comment: Hmm... The only thing I can think of is something like... well, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Dern... I wish that bash didn't throw that information away for history :( But this workaround seems good for now - thanks!